# Which C++ pattern to use for a library that allows extending its classes?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, polymorphism

I am trying to split some code off my C++ simulation software into a library, so it can be used more flexibly. The simulation is based on a `Lattice`, consisting of a number of `Node`s which hold lists of pointers to their `Neighbor`s. Although neighbors are also nodes, I'd like to have a little wrapper class around the `*Node` pointer in order to implement additional logic/fields (e.g., `bool is_neares_neighbor` or so.

My class architecture looks therefore something like this:

```
class Lattice {
private:
    vector<Node> _nodes;
};

class Node {
private:
    vector<Neighbor> _neighbors;
};

class Neighbor {
private:
    Node * _node;
};
```

So far, so good. Now, I would like my library to handle all the lattice-related logic, but nothing else. However, when using the library in some project, the three classes (`Lattice`, `Node`, `Neighbor`) will carry more logic and fields. The user should therefore be able to inherit from these classes and implement his/her custom stuff, while the library still handles all the necessary lattice-related logic.

What is the recommended way to do that? Are templates appropriate here? In a templated situation, my class hierarchy would look like this:

```
template<class N>
class Lattice {
private:
    vector<N> _nodes;
};

template<class NN>
class Node {
private:
    vector<NN> _neighbors;
};

template<class N>
class Neighbor {
private:
    N * _node;
};
```

As you can see, both `Node`  and `Neighbor` need to know the type of each other, which is a circular condition I have no idea how to deal with here. In addition, the whole library would have to live in header files.

How are situations like these dealt with in the C++ world in the most elegant way?

Comment: What are N and NN?  I think I have a solution to the question as asked, although I would still have some concerns about the raw pointer to node inside neighbor.

Comment: Are the types of Node and Neighbor really completely independent from each other? Doesn't a specific type of Node imply a specific type of Neighbor? I would imagine Node and Neighbor as abstract classes (interfaces) and derive the concrete Nodes and Neighbors from them. But maybe I got your requirement wrong.

Comment: Hey, thank you both for answering. @KennyOstrom: N and NN are classes derived from `Node` and `Neighbor`, respectively, that are provided by the user. So the user can add functions and variables to both the `Node` and `Neighbor` class. @FrankPuffer: They aren't dependent. A lot of meta information can exist in a relationship between two `Node`s, like counters, and so on. It is like a 1:n relationship where additional information about the relationship can be stored. However, this is probably the part I can most easily spare, if there is no other solution. I just want to make it very flexible.

Comment: Btw: Abstract classes are totally fine for me, I just don't know how to properly implement them. Would I need dynamic casting of pointers in that case? How do I "register" my derived classes to the library? I would know how to implement this in Java, using interfaces...

Comment: My gut feeling is that all vectors should hold pointers, not objects proper, or your users wouldn't be able to e.g. have their (i.e. your library-) Lattice hold custom (derived) nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking you want the template type to be the "some other type" that your lattice library does not know or care about.  So instead of having the user derive from Node, instead you use template<class t_data> for all your classes.

You said yourself, Neighbor is a Node, so you should be able to define everything in terms of Node<t_data>.

You should also consider how you are going to construct the lattice, and how you will return info about it.  Here is an example where I assume you create the lattice by having the lattice class create nodes, with the option to connect them to existing nodes at the time of creation.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

template<class t_data>
class SetOfNodes;

template<class t_data>
class Node {
public:
    Node(t_data value, SetOfNodes neighbors) : _data(value), _neighbors(neighbors) {}
    is_nearest_neighbor(const Node &other){
        // is other in _neighbors?
        // is other the closest neighbor?
        return false;
    }
private:
    t_data _data;
    SetOfNodes _neighbors;
};

template<class t_data>
class SetOfNodes {
public:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Node<t_data>>> _nodes;
};

template<class t_data>
class Lattice {
public:
    SetOfNodes get_all_nodes();
    void create_new_node(SetOfNodes neighbors);
private:
    SetOfNodes _nodes;
};
```

I don't really understand Neighbor, because either it is a Node, or it involves two nodes, so I'll leave that one alone.

Comment: technically your nodes don't have to have any type at all, but I assumed the point of this library was to work with some other type, and that's why you mentioned template

Comment: Hi Kenny, thank your for your suggestion. Your suggestion seems to to use some kind of additional data structure, that is simply added to my library's classes as member, while the library itself works with its own types. I will try that out later. It is a bit less elegant than I thought I could solve this, in that the user is forced to specify such a class and cannot use the library without it, but maybe it'll do.

Comment: None of the answers actually fitted my requirements very well, which is why I decided not to make an independent library of the lattice stuff. This answer would have been the best choice, though, so I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use a combination of Composite/Visitor pattern:

- Composite will help you defining a hierarchy of Lattice/Node/Neighbor/Custom_User_Node_Derived classes which can be treated uniformly (whatever the content is)
- Visitor will help you crawling the hierarchy and encapsulate the logic for your Lattice/Node/Neighbor class as well as letting the user define new operations that you can't actually predict yet.

It's a particularly recommended approach when you want to extend a library (or set of classes) on which you don't have control. From my understanding it's one of the thing you want your user being able to.